# Delete one row from DOM built table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is dynamically built using DOM. It has 10 cols, and on each row i have some data that i get from a websocket, text boxes and a submit button to add each row to the database.

How can i remove a row after i submitted it?
Someone mentioned jQuery but can't figure it out how to do that.

**EDIT**

I'm using Chrome and had problems with all the scripts below. this is how i resolved it:
instead of `$('input')` I used `jQuery('input')` all the scripts are working fine.
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
$('input').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('td').remove();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/32W63/

EDIT:

Here is another way to do this...

```
$('table form').submit(function() {
    // run some ajax here to do your database work
    $(this).closest('td').remove();
});
```

Comment: @wdm. Don't you think it'd just remove the `<td>` not the complete row? Why not `$(this).parent().parent().remove();`

Comment: this is exactly what i need. thanks for the great reply. but before do i remove the row, how can i pass the data from the cells to an mysql query to add them to the db?

Comment: @sebastian , do that before yous say .remove that should do it.

Comment: @kobe yes that should do it. but i want to do 2 things with the data, first add to db then remove when finished.

Comment: @sebastian here is an updated fiddle that may give you some additional clues to how this works. http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/32W63/2/

Comment: @wdm i keep getting an error with the first script `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null`

Comment: @sebastian create a demo with jsfiddle and i'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Assuming all your submit buttons have the same class
$(".submit").live("click", function(e){
   var buttonHnd = $(this);
   $.post("your-php-file.php", 
     {/* the data you want to post e.g. */ name: $("#name").val()},
     function(data){
      buttonHnd.parent().parent().remove();
     }
   );
});
});
```

Comment: thank you for your fast reply. sorry for the following beginner question. is `click` the class of the button? yes i use the same `name` tag for all the buttons. but would the `$.post` statement work if all the text boxes have the same `name` tag?

Comment: @sebastian - as you said the table data is coming dynamically you can't bind an event to it when the DOM is ready. Otherwise you could have used: `$(".submit").click(function(e){` instead. `.submit` is basically the class name of the button/anchor you want to bind this event to. for `$.post` please read: http://docs.jquery.com/Post

Comment: i tried your script with the `$.post` part disabled and i get an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (` on this line `function(data){` what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @sebastian - if you don't want to use the `$.post` part which means you don't want to do whatever your database via ajax, you can simply do `$(".submit").parent().parent().remove()`. Please note that `function(data)` is the part of `$.post`. If it's unclear I can give you a jsfiddle example

Comment: with the $.post function will the query in the php file be activated?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery' remove to remove it from dom...

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: @sebastian , you can put this remove in your logic , .remove completly removes from DOM

Comment: i've seen this page but it doesn't help. as i've said, my table is built automatically, i cannot make a difference between the rows.

Comment: @sebastian , i did't get the correct context , but you can defiently use jquery's various methods to find where you are and delete the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myTableRow = ... // Find the row however you like
myTableRow.parentNode.removeChild(myTableRow);
```

You might also be interested in my [AJAXFetch](http://phrogz.net/JS/AJAXFetch/) jQuery plug-in. Among other things, it lets you treat a row of a table as a form and submit all the form elements in it using AJAX, swapping it out the row with the result from the server (usually the non-form version). I use it in many of my internal applications for in-place editing of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
// Simple bottom row removal
$('#myTable tr:last').remove();
// Removing n'th (ex. 3rd) row from the table
$('#myTable tr:eq(2)').remove();
```

Source: [JQuery HowTo](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/remove-bottom-table-row-using-jquery.html)